# How to Know/Change PHP Java Bridge port number

Tags: java, php, security, glassfish, php-java-bridge

I have 2 machines:

1. First with PHP+Apache for WebApp (`10.1.1.33`)
2. Second with Glassfish for backend task and Reporting etc (`10.1.1.34`)

The first machine(Apache) can access Java.inc file from second machine(Glassfish)

```
http://10.1.1.34:8080/projectname/java/Java.inc
```

There is a firewall setting, that allows `8080` access from `Apache`(`10.1.1.33`) machine to `Glassfish` (`10.1.1.34`) machine. I think that is why `Java.inc` is accessible, however `PHP-Java-Bridge` reserves a separate port for rest of the communication. My application does not work until and unless I add that specific reserved port.
As a work around I have added a rule to allow any port from Apache machine.

```
allow 0-65535 from 10.1.1.33
```

Which does not seems to be good idea, as I have to close all the ports and allow only ports that are really required.

**Java side configuration**
Following jar files are copied to the lib folder of Java Web Project.

1. JavaBridge.jar
2. php-script.jar
3. php-servlet.jar

Here is part of `web.xml` of web project for bridge settings

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>php.java.servlet.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PhpJavaServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>PhpJavaServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.phpjavabridge</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

**Question:**

1. Is there a fix port reserved by php-java-bridge?
2. Can we find out what port is reserved?
3. Can we we specify our chosen port number?

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation states that you need to configure this yourself](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/desktop-apps.php)

---

> ## Add the PHP/Java Bridge library to your Java application
>
> 1. Copy JavaBridge.jar to the current directory.
> 2. Add JavaBridge.jar to your Java application. Edit the manifest MANIFEST.MF like this:
>
> Main-Class: HelloWorld
> Class-Path: JavaBridge.jar
>
> 3. Open a communication port for PHP. Edit HelloWorld.java like this:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static final String JAVABRIDGE_PORT="8087";
  static final php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner runner = 
    php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner.getInstance(JAVABRIDGE_PORT);

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    runner.waitFor();
    System.exit(0);
  }
  public void hello(String args[]) throws Exception {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hello " + args[0]);
  }
}
```

> 4. Recompile your Java application.

Comment: How can we verify that bridge is really using this port. other than deploying the application in above specified environment? wanted to test it locally.

Comment: The above method is for standalone application.